# Password Digest SOAP in Delphi

Tags: delphi, soap

Do anybody have encoded this in Delphi XE2 ?

```
Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + password ) )
```

It's to calculate the password digest for consuming SOAP services.

Thank's.

Comment: How are you 'consuming' your SOAP - which Delphi components. I'm asking because the XE2 SOAP components do a lot for you, e.g. supplying the password to the SOAP webservice.

Comment: yes i'm consuming the SOAP serice with XE2. i use the HTTPRIO and create the header with WSSE.pas. Finaly i'v found how to calculate the password_digest. But do you know another way to supply the header to the webservice ?

Comment: With a THTTPRIO you just set user name and password in the HTTPWebNode property, but I'm not sure how the type kind of password exchange (basic, NTLM) is set. With TidHTTP you set the IOHandler to e.g. TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL if you want SSL to be handled by the OpenSSL DLLS, and then in your uses clause you include units to handle the type of password exchange, e.g. IdAuthenticationNTLM

Comment: And for what it's worth, you can set any HTTP header in the THTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode.OnBeforePost, e.g. HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, PChar(CONTENT_HEADER_EX2010), Length(CONTENT_HEADER_EX2010), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE);